# Do they open the Bible during the court process?

Tags: united-states, rules-of-court, process, religion

Is the Bible being opened during the process in any state in USA in order to recite a quote from it or whatever? Do they swear on the open Bible or closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the Bible being opened during the process in any state in USA in order to recite a quote from it or whatever?

As part of the court procedure, no. I can imagine circumstances where parts of the bible (or any book) might be read into evidence or by or to witnesses as part of direct or cross examination.

> Do they swear on the open Bible or closed?

Where a witness chooses to swear on a bible the bible is closed.

Comment: You could swear or affirm on an issue of playboy as far as the law is concerned.

Comment: @victor No, swearing is a religious oath - Christians swear on the Bible, Muslims swear to Allah (not on the Quran) etc. Affirmations is *not* a religious practice and are not made on a text. As far as I know, Playboy is not the sacred text of any religion.

Comment: Not in the United States. You have freedom of religion. They cannot make you swear on those books

Comment: @Victor Do you not understand what "chooses" means? If you choose to swear on the Bible, then you use a Bible; if you choose to do something else, then you don't

Comment: @DaleM: *"As far as I know, Playboy is not the sacred text of any religion."* Key words: "***as far as I know.***"